# Как расставить знаки препинания, чтобы правильно выразить мысль?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Рассмотрим следующую фразу:

> Концерта завтра не будет, к сожалению, он переносится на следующую субботу.

*"К сожалению"* можно отнести и к первой, и ко второй части. Что надо сделать, чтобы было понятно, как прочитать? Разделить смысловые части точкой с запятой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы выбирал между точкой и двоеточием (после двоеточия раскрывается причина завтрашней отмены - событие, о котором сожалеют).

Если же намеренно отнести сожаление к первой части, то для письменной формы лучше перенести "к сожалению" в самое начало (чтобы не было впечатления сожаления, высказанного "вдогонку").

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё очень убедительно! Значит, точка с запятой точно не подойдёт, правильно я понимаю?

Comment: На мой взгляд, она разграничивает _разнородные_ смыслы, которые по какому-то замыслу сгруппированы объединением в общее предложение. А в нашем случае не видно причин дополнительно разделять логически связанные высказывания.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно)

Answer (score 2):

В середине прошлого века правила русского языка требовали в подобных случаях нагромождать знаки препинания либо усложнять стилистику текста другими способами. Но в последние десятилетия [эти правила](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2), к счастью, упрощаются:

> 4. Вводное слово на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения
>
> Вводные слова и сочетания, стоящие на границе однородных членов или
>   частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову
>   или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой:
>   *Послышался резкий стук, **должно быть** сорвалась ставня. А. Чехов, Невеста. (Ср.: Послышался резкий стук. Должно быть, сорвалась
>   ставня.)*

В соответствии с этим правилом предложение в любом случае читается однозначно: если оставить обе запятые, тогда *к сожалению* относится к первой части; если же оставить только первую запятую — тогда ко второй. Я надеюсь, что в будущем это правило упростится и достаточно будет ставить только одну из запятых (как и сейчас в случае вводных слов на границе основной части и обособленного оборота).

Comment: Спасибо, grizzly! Простите, забыл отреагировать тогда на ваш ответ. Интересная идея убирать запятую, но затрудняюсь сказать, одобряю я её или нет в конечном счёте.

Answer (score 2):

Артем, у меня вопрос к вашей правильной мысли. О чем мы сожалеем? О том, что концерта не будет?

Тогда вводное слово нужно **как-то отделить от второй части предложения**, иначе можно подумать, что мы сожалеем о переносе концерта, не хотим, чтобы он вообще состоялся. **Только постановкой знаков эту проблему не решишь.**

Возможны такие варианты:

***К сожалению***, концерта завтра не будет, он переносится на следующую субботу.

Или: *Концерта завтра не будет, **к сожалению, но** он переносится на следующую субботу.*

Comment: О чём сожалеем? Так меня и интересует, как расставить знаки в обоих случаях: когда мы сожалеем о том, что концерта не будет, и когда сожалеем о переносе. Ваши варианты для первого случая мне нравятся, спасибо! :)

Comment: А второй случай будет выглядеть, вероятно,  так: Концерта завтра не будет!  Но к сожалению, он переносится на следующую субботу.  Жаль, что у нас на форуме нет смайликов, они учень удобны. Иногда хочется сказать что-нибудь забавное, чтобы не скучно  было,  а шутки понимаются не всегда и не всеми.

Comment: Да, Sharon, это что-то с чем-то! Я тоже думал о втором смысле в том смысле, что, блин, зачем перенесли этот концерт на следующую неделю – мы не хотим  вообще никак и ни при каких обстоятельствах слышать (слушать) этот концерт!!!

Comment: Да блин, вы своим "но" всё исказили!!!)))) Не было сожаления, что он вообще состоится. ;)

Comment: Так в этом-то и весь смысл! Зачем вообще "к сожалению" относить ко второй части? Alex_ander и Sharon правильно говорят, что оно относится только к первой части.

Comment: *Зачем вообще "к сожалению" относить ко второй части?* Действительно, ни к чему, убедили! =)))

Comment: О, целая конференция!  А союз НО удачно вписался в предложение. Переставляешь его всего на одну позицию, и смысл сообщения кардинально меняется.